Do Cat Fall and Gliding Membranes work together?
Cat Fall:

Treat falls as 10 feet shorter

Gliding Membranes:

Treat falls as 25 feet shorter

When I have both, do I treat falls 35 feet shorter?
They are not bonuses, so should work together, but I am not sure.

Aren't those typed effects?

I don't think so, but that is why I asked

Yes
The rules which prevent modifiers of the same type from applying cumulatively don't apply here, as:

Treating falls as some feet shorter isn't a bonus or penalty
Even if they were considered modifiers, they'd be untyped penalties to fall damage and both apply by those same rules:


Unlike bonuses, penalties can also be untyped, in which case they won't be classified as “circumstance,” “item,” or “status.” Unlike other penalties, you always add all your untyped penalties together rather than simply taking the worst one.


If they were a modifier, they would be a bonus not a penalty so the quoted rule doesn't apply. The first point still stands as our only (afaik) guidance on ruling this one.

You say the modification of fall hight, which is clearly positive to the falling one, is a penalty? That is... possibly a stretch... but the other point works very well.

By definition, a bonus is a beneficial thing and a penalty is not. If you were to penalize fall damage, you would be increasing it because damage is bad. I'm not saying it is a bonus, only that it is clearly not a penalty by any use of the word in-game or out.

@Ifusaso'he-him' Interesting, I'd never checked the common language definition as possibly distinct from the in-game bonus/penalty as mathematically positive/negative modifiers. I still find the hypothetical -25 foot penalty to fall damage clearer than something like a -25 foot bonus to fall damage, or as a 25 foot bonus to reducing fall damage, but thanks for clarifying.
